# Converting from Version 4 to Version 5: Problem with Compilation

Tags: compilation, solidity-0.5.x

I got the following Solidity code from:
https://www.zupzup.org/smart-contract-interaction/

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.6;

contract Caller {
    function someAction(address addr) returns(uint) {
        Callee c = Callee(addr);
        return c.getValue(100);
    }
    function storeAction(address addr) returns(uint) {
        Callee c = Callee(addr);
        c.storeValue(100);
        return c.getValues();
    }
    
    function someUnsafeAction(address addr) {
        addr.call(bytes4(keccak256("storeValue(uint256)")), 100);
    }
}

contract Callee {
    function getValue(uint initialValue) returns(uint);
    function storeValue(uint value);
    function getValues() returns(uint);
}
```

When I compile, I get following errors:

> Compiled Yetcontracts/Caller.sol:17:9: TypeError: Wrong argument count
> for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1. This function
> requires a single bytes argument. If all your arguments are value
> types, you can use abi.encode(...) to properly generate it.
> addr.call(bytes4(keccak256("storeValue(uint256)")), 100);
> ^------------------------------------------------------^

Somebody please guide me how to get rid of the compilation error?

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from 0.5, an explicit description of the function visibility zone is required, and the **abi.encodeWithSignature** function is used to generate the call data:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.6;

contract Caller {
    function someAction(address addr) public returns(uint) {
        Callee c = Callee(addr);
        return c.getValue(100);
    }
    function storeAction(address addr) public returns(uint) {
        Callee c = Callee(addr);
        c.storeValue(100);
        return c.getValues();
    }
    
    function someUnsafeAction(address addr) public {

         (bool  result,)=addr.call( abi.encodeWithSignature("storeValue(uint256)", 100) );
    if(result==false) {
//                          Call result processing
                      }

    }
}

contract Callee {
    function getValue(uint initialValue) public returns(uint);
    function storeValue(uint value) public ;
    function getValues() public returns(uint);
}
```